# Customize feed for WCF Data Services using Entity Framework (Code First)

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services, odata

Can anybody tell me how to customize the OData feed for Ado.Net Data Services using Entity Framework (Code First/Only)?

There is no EDMX file (as it is Code Only).

I have tried adding the attribute:

```
[EntityPropertyMapping( "Id" , SyndicationItemProperty.Title , SyndicationTextContentKind.Plaintext , true )]
```

To my POCO entity classes but nothing shows up in the feed title tag?

UPDATE:

If I was using an EDMX file I could customize the feed by applying attributes like this:

```
<EntityType Name="Customer">
  <Property Name="myAddress" Type="MyModelNamespace.Address"
        me:EpmSourcePath="Street"
        m2:FC_Atom="true"
        m2:FC_TargetPath="EpmSyndicationTitle"
        m2:FC_ContentKind="EpmPlaintext"
        m2:FC_KeepContent="true"/>
</EntityType>
```

But I am not using an EDMX file - I am using Code Only. My question is about achieving the same thing when using Code Only (no XML file).

Thanks!

Comment: It would seem this cannot be done:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/b237d3d7-29c2-4676-9b49-023c677f3891

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the access rules for your entity sets?

as a catch all for testing you should have something like:

```
public class NorthwindService : DataService<NorthwindEntities>
{
   public static void InitializeService(IDataServiceConfiguration config)
   {
      config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Doobi. I do have the access rules working fine. It isn't about missing data - it all gets returned. It is just about copying/moving some of the data into the <title></title> section of the OData feed (something that is very easy when using the Reflection Provider or Entity Framework with an EDMX file).